# How to avoid any FK-entity loading, but still use FK-entity in HQL?

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a parent entity **DBParentEntity** that have relation to FK-entity **DBForeignEntity**.

```
@Entity
@Table(catalog = "my_schema", name = "my_table")
public class DBParentEntity {

   ...

   private DBForeignEntity foreign;

   @ManyToOne
   @JoinColumn(name = "foreign_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
   public DBForeignEntity getForeign() {
       return foreign;
   }

   public void setForeign(DBForeignEntity foreign) {
       this.foreign = foreign;
   }
}
```

How to avoid any loading FK-entity, but still use it in HQL?
I want to load foreign entity with my own cached method

```
private int foregnId;

@Basic
@Column(name = "foreign_id")
public int getForegnId() {
    return foregnId;
}

public void setForegnId(int foregnId) {
    this.foregnId = foregnId;
}

private DBForeignEntity foreign;
private boolean hasForeign;
@Transient
public DBForeignEntity getForeign() {
    if (!hasForeign) {
        initForeign();
    }
    return foreign;
}

@Transient
private synchronized void initForeign() {
    if (hasForeign) return;
    foreign = getFromCache(foregnId)
    if (foreign!= null) hasForeign= true;
}
```

I can drop @ManyToOne annotation at all and replace it with @Transient, 
but all relations HQL will fail:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from DBParentEntity parent where parent.!foreign!.more_foregn.some_field = :some_value ")
```